# Android - Get the SIM slot for the current cellular network

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have an Android dual-sim device, with 2 SIM cards. The cellular connectivity is up and running, how may I know which SIM card is used as current network (and so which SIM slot)? I don't know how to make the link between the current active network given by the ConnectivityManager and the bunch of data returned by the TelephonyManager. Any help appreciated, thanks!